# SwiftUI NavigationView on MacOS leaves padding above List

Tags: macos, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink

I have a NavigationView that leaves what looks like padding above the List of NavigationLink's and I can't work out how to get rid of it?
[image: Weird NavigationView bug]

Here's the view that calls the NavigationView:

```swift
struct SearchView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var networkManager:NetworkManager
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            SearchBar()//<- This view houses the content above the list but contains no padding after the divider and when the filesToDisplay is false it shrinks to the divider as expected
            if networkManager.filesToDisplay {
                ResultsView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the NavigationView:

```swift
struct ResultsView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var networkManager:NetworkManager
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(networkManager.FileList!.items) { file in
                    NavigationLink(destination: FileDetail(fileDetail: file)) {
                        FileRow(fileRow: file)
                    }
                }
            }
            Rectangle().frame(maxWidth: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
            }.frame(minHeight:500, idealHeight: 550, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}
```

I thought the problem might be to do with navigationBarTitle but MacOS does not appear to use this?  I've tried all sorts of different padding and listRowInsets but nothing is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add explicit spacing

```
VStack(spacing: 0) {   // << here !!
    SearchBar()
    if networkManager.filesToDisplay {
        ResultsView()
    }
}
```